# Too many arguments to 'Public Function MsgBox...'

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have an error like this:

> Too many arguments to 'Public Function MsgBox(Prompt As Object, [Buttons As Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly], [Title As Object = Nothing]) As Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult'.

And my code is like this:

```
Private Sub LogoutToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LogoutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo, MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Logout") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Form6.ShowDialog()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

And I don't know why this error is occurring. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is intellisense broken on your VS install?  Much easier and faster to read the help VS offers than to post a poor question here

Comment: Get rid of the `MsgBoxStyle.Question` parameter.

Comment: Side note; by using `ShowDialog()`, `Me.Close()` won't actually be called until `Form6` is closed as `ShowDialog()` will block the thread. Also in future please make sure you give a better title, _vb.net 2010 logout system_ is not at all helpful.

Comment: According to your error, `MsgBox` takes 3 arguments and you are passing it 4!  Pretty clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Using the proper [MessageBox.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598709(v=vs.110).aspx) overload (instead of the legacy `MsgBox` function), it should look like this:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Logout", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    Form6.ShowDialog()
    Me.Close()
End If
```